# Files added to assets slows testing

Tags: android, eclipse

I've added several thousand files to my assets and suddenly it takes a minute to start when debugging from eclipse.  Is there a way to have it not recopy all the asset files over each time?

Comment: `assets` or `resources`? I have a project with 17k+ files in `resources` and it doesn't seem to slow it down. How large are your files?

Comment: He mentions `assets`. I've also experienced a similar issue in the past and it slowed down the debugging. Doubt this is related to Eclipse though.

Comment: I'm just asking for clarification, since many sites/blogs refer to all of it as a generalized "assets", and it's an industry-accepted term for gfx/media. Even Google does on occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to have it not recopy all the asset files over each time?

No, other than to don't put them in `assets/`, but instead access them in some other fashion (e.g., external storage).

Note that the Play Store has a 50MB limit on the size of your APK file, in case your problem is literally in the transfer time to the device or emulator.

Comment: What are the benefits to use the `assets` folder then?

Comment: @Houf: Compared to what? In another probably-related question, the OP asked to add "a few thousand image files in a directory structure... to my app and access these images? Assuming I want foo/bar/1.png?" The only solution there is assets, as resources do not support the directory structure. However, adding "a few thousand image files... to my app" has issues in general, APK size being one of them. `assets/` does not somehow magically make files take up no size.

Comment: You suggested to access the files from another location, external storage. I was just wondering if there are some drawbacks from doing this instead of using the assets folder. But I agree, that's another topic than the OP question :) In the case of this question, that would resolve the issue of slowing the debugging session.

Comment: What I'm doing is keeping an empty assets folder while writing/testing other functionality. This is error prone and not recommended but android has to copy over all of the assets which for example xcode doesn't do for iPhone testing.